# Passing Props down to children, without importing the child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component like this:

```
const Foo = ({ size ) => {
    return <Bar size={size}>
        {children}
    </Bar>
```

Then I use `<Foo />` in `<AnotherComponent />`

```
const AnotherComponent = () => {
    <Foo size='gigantic'>
        <WhatEverest />
    <Foo />
```

I then want to use the `size` prop, passed to `<Foo />` in `<AnotherComponent />` to be available to its children, without passing it explicitly to `<WhatEverest />`.

Is there a way to edit `<Foo />` accordingly to make this possible?

Comment: You can use [`useContext`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) for that.

Comment: @ChrisG Yeah, that would be a solution. But in order to pass only one prop down, `context` is a little too much overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of Foo can add any number of properties to the children:

```
const Foo = ({ size, children }) => {
  return (
    <Bar size={size}>
      {
        React.Children.map(children, (element) => React.cloneElement(element,{size}))
      }
    </Bar>
  );
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, because using `context()` is just a little bit too much for only passing one prop down the line. But what you are suggesting is not working. How do I access `size` in the children component?

Comment: Well the children should be able to access `size` with `props.size` like any other prop. Ah maybe I understodd the [cloneElement docu](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html) wrong. Try `React.cloneElement(element, { size } )`
I mistook it for an array, fixed it now.